# Zephyr-RTOS logging with DMA on STM32L432KC

Tags: stm32, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to run Zephyr Logging by using DMA on UART on STM32L432KC.

That's simple main loop:

```
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>

LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(example, LOG_LEVEL_DBG);

int main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        LOG_INF("main loop");
        k_msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

That's full configuration:

```
CONFIG_SOC_SERIES_STM32L4X=y
CONFIG_SOC_STM32L432XX=y

# Enable MPU
CONFIG_ARM_MPU=y

# Enable HW stack protection
CONFIG_HW_STACK_PROTECTION=y

# enable uart driver
CONFIG_SERIAL=y

# enable GPIO
CONFIG_GPIO=y

# Enable Clocks
CONFIG_CLOCK_CONTROL=y

# console
CONFIG_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UART_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UART_ASYNC_API=y

# enable DMA
CONFIG_DMA=y

# enable pin controller
CONFIG_PINCTRL=y

# config logging
CONFIG_LOG=y
CONFIG_LOG_BACKEND_UART_ASYNC=y
CONFIG_LOG_MODE_IMMEDIATE=y
```

Then build it and flash:

```
west flash -b nucleo_l432kc
```

In logs I see following output:

```
*** Booting Zephyr OS build zephyr-v3.2.0-863-g78809549ee4c  ***
[00:00:01.001,000] <inf> example: main loop
```

When I change `CONFIG_LOG_MODE_IMMEDIATE=y` to `CONFIG_LOG_MODE_DEFERRED=y` it prints log every second like I expect.

I discovered that code stops [here](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/6be9666ba23118a53e1cdd5afedbd11339551c84/subsys/logging/backends/log_backend_uart.c#L82) on `k_sem_take(&sem, K_FOREVER)` and [this](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/6be9666ba23118a53e1cdd5afedbd11339551c84/subsys/logging/backends/log_backend_uart.c#L30) `uart_callback` is never called to release this mutex.

Also discovered when following options are enabled it's working fine with `CONFIG_LOG_MODE_DEFERRED=y` option:

```
CONFIG_LOG_PROCESS_THREAD=y
CONFIG_LOG_PROCESS_THREAD_SLEEP_MS=100
```

But that makes me wondering why another thread must be created? DMA is no blocking. Really confusing.

What am I missing? I would like to delegate all logging to `DMA` buffer with `Logging` subsystem features, without additional threads and buffering. Is there someone experienced who can point what is wrong?

Comment: Try with `CONFIG_UART_INTERRUPT_DRIVEN`

Comment: @Flexz didn't help. Documantation says this option is for RX.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure console UART to use DMA in the device tree, as described in https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/build/dts/api/bindings/dma/st,stm32-dma-v2.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34489679)